# Complex V-If inside a computed property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to add a complex v-if statement that works within the template but as I'm adding more to it is getting too much to handle within the template.

I've added the statement into a computed property which throws an error during the evaluation of the computed property. Any ideas?

```
<div v-for="offer in offers" class="grid-4 item hotel hotel-item" v-if="showOffer"> 
<!-- OFFER CONTENT HERE --> 
</div>



computed: {
  showOffer() {
    return (offer.island === filters.islandFilter || filters.islandFilter === 'All') &&
      (offer.starrating === filters.starRating || filters.starRating === 'All') &&
      (offer.board === filters.boardBasis || filters.boardBasis === 'All') &&
      (offer.duration === filters.duration || filters.duration === 'All') &&
      (offer.price.from < filters.price)
  }
}
```

I'm trying to return each 'offer' in the offers data property that is true to the V-if statement.

Comment: did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** :

- when you are within your `<script>` tag, you need to put `this` in front of the variable you want to access from your vue `data`. For example, in your code, use `this.filters.islandFilter` instead of `filters.islandFilter`. `filters.islandFilter` is the syntax to use when accessing `filters` from the template, not from within the script tag.
- You are trying to access `offer` in your computed property, but your method is not aware of what `offer` is. You can use a method instead of a computed property and call `showOffer(offer)` instead. but the good practice is to use filters on your data (see next paragraph)

**Then :**

`v-for` and `v-if` statement do not mix well in most cases. If you want to render only some of your `offers`, you should create a computed property which returns the list of your filtered offer, and then use v-for on that.

Example,
in your template tag :

```
<div v-for="offer in filteredOffers" class="grid-4 item hotel hotel-item"> 
      <!-- OFFER CONTENT HERE --> 
</div>
```

in your script tag :

```
  data: {
    offers: [
       //your list of offers
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    filteredOffers () {
      return this.offers.filter(offer => {
        return (offer.island === this.filters.islandFilter || this.filters.islandFilter === 'All') &&
          (offer.starrating === this.filters.starRating || this.filters.starRating === 'All') &&
          (offer.board === this.filters.boardBasis || this.filters.boardBasis === 'All') &&
          (offer.duration === this.filters.duration || this.filters.duration === 'All') &&
          (offer.price.from < this.filters.price)
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: with pleasure. Also, adding the precise error thrown during evaluation to your post could help us pinpoint the problem in case my answer does not work :)

Comment: Works perfectly - thank you Tom, exactly what I was looking to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a method instead of using a computed property, by passing `offer` as a parameter like :

```
  <div v-for="offer in offers" class="grid-4 item hotel hotel-item" v-if="showOffer(offer)"> 
      <!-- OFFER CONTENT HERE --> 
  </div>
```

```
methods: {

  showOffer(offer) {
    return (offer.island === filters.islandFilter || filters.islandFilter === 'All') &&
      (offer.starrating === filters.starRating || filters.starRating === 'All') &&
      (offer.board === filters.boardBasis || filters.boardBasis === 'All') &&
      (offer.duration === filters.duration || filters.duration === 'All') && (offer.price.from < filters.price)

  }

}
```

but i recommend another approach using computed property that returns an array which filters your `offers` one by returning the items which fit the given condition and removing the `v-if` directive :

```js
computed: {
  comp_offers() {
    return this.offers.filter((offer) => {

      return (offer.island === filters.islandFilter || filters.islandFilter === 'All') &&
        (offer.starrating === filters.starRating || filters.starRating === 'All') &&
        (offer.board === filters.boardBasis || filters.boardBasis === 'All') &&
        (offer.duration === filters.duration || filters.duration === 'All') && (offer.price.from < filters.price)

    })
  }

}
```

```html
<div v-for="offer in comp_offers" class="grid-4 item hotel hotel-item">
  <!-- OFFER CONTENT HERE -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately Vue dev tools returns the error - comp_offers:"(error during evaluation)"

Comment: please update your question with what you try and what did you get

Comment: I copied your exact computed property solution which returned the error. No luck with your methods solution either. The offers data property is an array of objects if that makes any difference.

Comment: please provide more details, i think both of methods should work

Comment: based on what you provided my solution should work, please provide a screenshot of that errors  when you try the both of methods

Comment: You were missing **this**.filters.islandFilter from the computed as per Tom's solution below. Thank you for your help though.